# How to let the program to to show the Gui Code before executing the next line of code in GWT?

Tags: gwt, user-interface

I have a Panel with a radio button & a info Label on it. I want that when user clicks on that radio button, the Label will `infoLabel.setText("...loading data....");`, then the program will run a long loop that could take 5 seconds. When the loop finishes the program will `infoLabel.setText("data was loaded");`

```
    final RadioButton yesRadioButton=new RadioButton("confirm","Yes");
    yesRadioButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                infoLabel.setText("...loading data....");
                //long loop here
                for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; ++i) {
                    citiesOracle.add(cities[i]);}
                infoLabel.setText("data was loaded");

         }
    });
```

The above code doesn't work properly. When i check the radio button, the program was frozen for 5 sec & then it showed Label "data was loaded". I didn't see the Label show "...loading data...." before it ran the loop.

So the program ran the loop immediately right after i click the radio button & it didn't give a chance for the Label to show "...loading data...." first before showing "data was loaded"

So How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the label to the loading text, then you use the GWT Scheduler (http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html)

```
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
             for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; ++i) {
                    citiesOracle.add(cities[i]);}
                infoLabel.setText("data was loaded");
            }
        }
    });
```

JavaScript (in a browser) is single threaded, so your label changed is queued to be updated after the click event. Using the Scheduler makes the browser able to process the label change before the loop.

EDIT:
This resource gives a better example how to use the Scheduler to execute long, CPU intensive processing, without triggering the browser alert of "slow script" or "unresponsive script" http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html#incremental

Comment: Thax u for ur answer. Seem it is he only solution for this kind of issue, no other solution right?